# How do you check if a specific user reacts to a specific message with many specific emojis

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently making a car economy bot and I wanted to be able to interact with the bot just like how a game would. I wanted to use reactions for buttons but the problem was that when I used the code,

```py
confirm_right = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=react_check_right) 
confirm_left = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=react_check_left)
```

It didn't work as expected, first it waits for the confirm_right then the confirm_left.

I'm hoping to find a way to be able to make them both work at the same time.

This is my check functions,

```py
def check(message):
        return ctx.author.id == message.author.id

    def react_check_right(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["➡️"]
```

Comment: Can you also add the check functions to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

````py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji in ["➡️", "⬅️"])

        if user == ctx.author:
            if reaction.emoji == '➡️':
                if car_shown < len(users[str(user.id)]['car']) - 1:
                    car_shown += 1
                else:
                    car_shown = 0
    ```
this was basically it
````